# Regex quotes and not a specific word before quotes

Tags: c#, regex, quotes

What I'm trying to do is that simple but the same time is not.

I have a function of RegEx in C# to find all the words inside quotes,
But if a specific word exist before the quotes, Ignore the whole word and continue to the next row.
While still looking for a specific kind of symbols inside the quotes and Ignore too.

Example -

```
My RegEx = @"(?<!Foo\()\""[^{}\r\n]*\""";

Text -
dontfindme1 = "Hello{}"
dontfindme2 = Foo("ABC")
findme1 = "Just a simple text to find"
findme2 = SuperFoo("WORKS")
```

Output example -

```
"ABC"
"Just a simple text to find"
"WORKS"
```

Now my problem is that I dont want to find the name "Foo(" before the quotes
And I dont want to find "{" or "}" or "(" or ")" or new lines
I only need "ABC" not to be found and skip to the next row.

Comment: Chance the `.` to `(`. Now the dot matches any character. Try [`(?<!Foo\()\"[^{}\r\n]*\"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!Foo%5c%28%29%5c%22%5b%5e%7b%7d%5cr%5cn%5d*%5c%22&i=Hello%7b%7d%0d%0a%22tesat%22%0d%0aFoo%22test%22%0d%0aFoo%28%22%22%29%0d%0a%22%7btest%22)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did tried this one and VS2017 tells me I have an "unrecognized escape sequence"...

Comment: Try it prepending an `@` like `string pattern = @"(?<!Foo\()\""[^{}\r\n]*\""";`

Comment: Now it works without the error, But still finding quotes that having 'Foo(' before them.

Comment: Can you add an example? Are all the words on their own row or are there multiple words?

Comment: Every word quotes have their own row. I updated example output

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!` to check that the string does not match either `{}` between double quotes or `Foo(`

`^(?!.*\bFoo\()(?!.*"[^"\r\n]*[{}][^"\r\n]*").*$`

In C# `string pattern = @"^(?!.*\bFoo\()(?!.*""[^""\r\n]*[{}][^""\r\n]*"").*$";`

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!.*%5cbFoo%5c%28%29%28%3f!.*%22%5b%5e%22%5cr%5cn%5d*%5b%7b%7d%5d%5b%5e%22%5cr%5cn%5d*%22%29.*%24&i=%22tesat%22%0d%0aFoo%22test%22%0d%0aFoo%28%22%22%29%0d%0aFoo%28%22%22%29+Foo%28%22%22%29%0d%0aFoo%5b%22%22%5d%0d%0a%22%7btest%22%0d%0aFoo%28%22ABC%22%29%0d%0aJust+a+simple+text+to+find%0d%0aSuperFoo%28%22WORKS%22%29&o=m)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that what follows does not

  - `.*\bFoo\(` Match any character 0+ times followed by a word boundary and Foo(
- `)` Close negative lookahead
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that what follows does not

  - `.*` Match any character 0+ times
  - `"[^"\r\n]*` Match a double quote, match 0+ times not `"`, `\r`, `\n`
  - `[{}]` Match `{` or `}`
  - `[^"\r\n]*"` Match 0+ times not `"`, `\r`, `\n` followed by matching a double quote
- `)` Close negative lookahead
- `.*` Match any character 0+ times
- `$` Assert the end of the string